# Laravel Spark Github connection

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-spark

I have been building and running a project using Laravel spark for several months now. A few days ago, my heroku commits started getting refused access to the github repo for spark.

The error that I was getting was the same one as on this page:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/spark-install-fails-to-production-server

It appears that you need to also link your github to spark's, but the project is on bitbucket so I am very confused.

https://spark.laravel.com/settings#/github

I am also confused as to why this isn't really covered anywhere in the docs. At least not that I can find. This is holding up production for everyone everywhere as we can't commit anything because of this.

Comment: Spark is commercial software. Have you tried contacting the developer?

Comment: Yes. There seems to be confusion about whether not this is actually needed. It isn't in the docs and my repo worked fine for months. They told me to make their code a path repo instead. I am working on doing this as a patch but I don't consider it a solution